# Ajax replace number dot to comma not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a function that obtains numbers from inputs fields, the numbers are with comma instead of dots on decimals (123,5), so what i do is conver them with replace to make the calculations and then replace them again to comma to display the results but it is giving me problems in the last replace, which is in an ajax return

The error: `"ncaught TypeError: subt1.replace is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onreadystatechange"`

I get the calculations right but when i try to convert it to comma decimal doesnt work
I supose is because the typing but i dont get it right

heres my code

```
function updateCarrito(id,precio,moneda) {

    var cant=document.getElementsByName("carrito_cantidad_"+id)[0].value;

    var ajax=nuevoAjax();

    var contenedor=parent.document.getElementById('iconCarrito');

    var subt1=document.getElementById('cantidad_compra1_'+id).value;

    if (moneda==1){
        var tot=document.getElementById('total_compra_pesos').value;
    }else{
        var tot=document.getElementById('total_compra_dolares').value;
    }

    subt1 = subt1.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
    tot = tot.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');

    ajax.open("GET", "http://www.somestuff.com?req=updateCarrito&id="+id+"&cant="+cant+"&precio="+precio,true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (ajax.readyState==4) {
            contenedor.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

                tot=(tot-subt1);
                subt1=(precio*cant);
                subt1 = subt1.replace('.', ',');

                document.getElementById('cantidad_compra1_'+id).value=subt1;

                tot=(tot+subt1);
                tot = tot.replace('.', ',');

                if (moneda==1){
                    document.getElementById('total_compra_pesos').value=tot;
                    document.getElementById('total_compra_pesos2').value=tot;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('total_compra_dolares').value=tot;
                    document.getElementById('total_compra_dolares2').value=tot;
                }

        } 
    };

    ajax.send(null);

}
```

Comment: You are rewriting the value of `subt1` in `subt1=(precio*cant);`. I think it is no longer a string, its a number now. And `.replace` method is available only for strings.

Comment: Yes, you are right but i couldnt figure out how to transform it to change that, i am using numComma = (subt1.toString()).replace(".", ","); now and testing it, seems to work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ways to convert a number to a string:

```
subt1 = String(precio*cant)
subt1 = (precio*cant).toString()
subt1 = (precio*cant) + ''
```

`subt1.replace` will work as expected after using any one of these methods

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling replace on a number instead of a string. `subt1=(precio*cant);` will change the type from string to number.

You need to cast before calling replace.

```
subt1 = subt1.toString().replace('.', ',');
```

edit: looks like I was beaten in the comments.